# Bidirectional relationships in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a "friend" relationship, as in "social site friends", which means: if I'm friending you you invariably friend me. If I remove you from friends, you do that, too. (well, you get the idea).

Currently this is done with duplicate relations and an observer to add/remove the second (more correctly, "other") relation when the first gets created/deleted.

What's the convenient way to implement the subject *without* duplicating records in the relation table? Maybe there's a gem/plugin to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there is a Railscast [on this very topic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)! Or if you prefer, you can read the instructions as an [ASCIIcast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association).